# How can I modify a Settings.bundle in real time?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

is there anyway to add new entries to the Settings bundle during run time?

We would like to be able to turn-off and on options depending on what information the user have entered. Seems like all Apple documentation talks about modifying preferences, but not the **Setings page** itself.

thanks!

Comment: it depends on which preferences you wanna change... you can surely edit some of them, as the "Status bar is initially hidden" with the code ->  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings.bundle is read-only. You can NOT modify it during run time.

If you want to be able to change settings during run time, you have include the app settings from within the app.